# Which framework/toolkit for modern unity applications?

Tags: application-development, gui, gtk, qt, interface

I want to code some applications for ubuntu (no other platforms), but which gui-toolkit would be the "official" one... in the past (gnome) gtk+ was my choice, but afaik unity uses Nux. I don't want to use these standard buttons and "old style ui". Qt would be great for KDE but what's the latest "unity" toolkit suggestion?

ps: programming language would be C/C++ or python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use any specific toolkit to interface with Unity, all of it's APIs are available via GObject Introspection.  This means you can use them with multiple languages and multiple toolkits.  You are free to use Gtk or Qt, C/C++ or Python, or any other combination of language and toolkit you prefer.

You can see the Unity APIs here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/api/12-04/

Answer (score 1):

## Gtk+

Gtk is the default tool kit of gnome ,so it is better to use gtk ,even then qt is well supported in ubuntu . So you can use it also ,nux is used in unity launcher and dash only . It is not suitable for creating desktop apps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean when you say unity and ubuntu-specific applications. You want to make a notification plugin of some sort?

Both Qt and GTK+ frameworks are preinstalled (I think) in ubuntu 12.04, so programs in either framework wouldn't have any problems.

You could try: Qt creator or Anjuta IDE (both available in ubuntu software center).
See which one fulfills your needs. :)